# How to catch a database exception in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsexception

I have searched a lot on the internet on catching an sqlite exception.But all I could come across was this general exception

```
@catch (NSException *exception) {

        }
```

What type of exception can I use for sqlite exception handling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, SQLite does not return exceptions for recoverable errors. Rather, it returns an error code which you must check after each operation.

Some "wrapper" APIs for SQLite may return exceptions, but that would be a function of the particular API.